# How to prevent horizontal scroll of my right-side popup panel in iOS4?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, jquery-mobile

For some reason my iOS app right popup panel and content is scrolling horizontally  Any ideas why this may happen?

Thanks !

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a UIScrollView then use this

```
self.rightSideScrollView.alwaysBouncesHorizontal=NO;
```

Then make sure that the

```
self.rightSideScrollView.contentSize.width
```

is not greater the the bounds of the self.rightSideScrollView.